# NUnit tests: Is IDisposable guaranteed if a non-expected exception is thrown?

Tags: exception, nunit, idisposable

If I create an IDisposable during the TestFixtureSetup of an NUnit test, and the test throws an unanticipated exception (e.g. external resource fails), will the IDisposable's Dispose() get called?

Added>>
If not, does NUnit provide guaranteed execution of TestFixtureTearDown or somewhere else that can be used for cleanup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it won't be called. [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) is used for deterministic finalization usually used in conjunction with the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx) statement. You could call the [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method in the `TestFixtureTearDown` though.

Comment: Note that `TestFixtureTearDown` **won't** be called if `TestFixtureSetUp` fails or throws an exception: 

"So long as any TestFixtureSetUp method runs without error, the TestFixtureTearDown method is guaranteed to run. It will not run if a TestFixtureSetUp method fails or throws an exception." [NUnit TestFixtureTearDownAttribute Documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureTeardown&r=2.6.4)

Comment: As of NUnit 2.4, `Dispose()` will be called on your TestFixture, so that gives another place you put your cleanup code.  [Release notes on 2.4 Alpha](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.4.1): "If the object implements IDisposable, Dispose is called before destroying it"